# MYSQL Order By Using EBCDIC instead of ASCII

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

Is there a way to have mysql sort or order by using EBCDIC instead of ASCII using a statement

Answer (score 2):

There's a collation for this [surprisingly](http://lists.mysql.com/mysql/180802), but you would've found that with Google.

Comment: Somehow he needs to use EBCDIC but doesn't know about collations.  Weird.